# Jquery replacing image issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following script to change an image based on the value entered.

```
var siteLogo = $('input#site-logo').val();
$('#site-logo, img').attr("src", siteLogo);
```

html

```
 <div id=site-logo>
<img src="default.png" width="285px" height="100px">
</div>

<input id="site-logo" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="http://" type="text">
<button id="add-site-logo" class="btn" href=""> Add</button>
```

My issue is that it's changing **ALL** the images on the page to the value in site-logo. How do I make it so that **ONLY** the value in site-logo gets changed and not other random stuff on the page?

Comment: id should be unique.Here you used id="site-logo" twice.

Comment: Dont use input#site-logo selector it is slower than #site-logo.

Comment: [Document yourself, document yourself](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove ',' from jQuery selector

```
$('#site-logo img').attr("src", siteLogo);
```

`$('#site-logo img')` means all images inside `#site-logo`

`$('#site-logo, img')` means `#site-logo` plus all images.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var siteLogo = $('input#site-logo').val();
$('#site-logo img').attr("src", siteLogo);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here:

- You have an `id` field set for two elements. It should be unique.
- The selector you're using selects multiple things: the `#site-logo` selector selects an item with the `site-logo` ID, the `img` selects all images on your page. The comma in the selectors defines basically an "or" across all your selectors; it will select an element if it matches `#site-logo` *or* it matches `img`.

Change your selector to this:

```
$("#site-logo img").attr("src", siteLogo);
```

You'll want a different id for your `<input>` tag in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$('img','#site-logo')
```

Or better:

```
$('#site-logo').find('img')
```